# Why tooltip doesn't place at bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tooltip

This is the element with the tooltip:

```
<div id="pencilTooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit Profile" data-placement="bottom">
    <div class="fa fa-pencil editProfilePencil" data-target="#editProfileModal"
         data-toggle="modal">
    </div>
</div>
```

The js to activate the tooltip and give the placement option:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    $('#pencilTooltip').tooltip({
        placement: 'bottom'
    });
```

Even though the tooltip is at the top and I don't understand why ?

Comment: try this one `data-placement="bottom"` add it on the `div` tag

Comment: Which tooltip library are you using? Also, is the div positioned absolutely? Sometimes that can cause issues

Comment: @NelsonTan ... OP already has that?

Comment: The div with pencil icon has an absolute position

Comment: That sounds likely to be your problem.  Again, the fix depends on the CSS and the library you're using, so if you need help with that you'll need to update your question to include that information

Comment: Above code seems working using JqueryUI. Here is [link](https://jsfiddle.net/ashishbpatil1/ctbdpfju/)